# Why a new .Net Aspire project won't start when it has a docker container?

Tags: docker, dotnet-aspire

A new .Net Aspire project won't start when it has a docker container.

```
C:\AspireSample\AspireSample.AppHost>dotnet run
Building...
info: Aspire.Dashboard.DashboardWebApplication[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:15187
info: Aspire.Dashboard.DashboardWebApplication[0]
      OTLP server running at: http://localhost:16199
fail: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host[11]
      Hosting failed to start
      System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
       ---> System.Net.Http.HttpIOException: The response ended prematurely. (ResponseEnded)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.EstablishProxyTunnelAsync(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp2ConnectionAsync(QueueItem queueItem)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
         at k8s.Kubernetes.SendRequestRaw(String requestContent, HttpRequestMessage httpRequest, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at k8s.AbstractKubernetes.ICustomObjectsOperations_CreateClusterCustomObjectWithHttpMessagesAsync[T](Object body, String group, String version, String plural, String dryRun, String fieldManager, Nullable`1 pretty, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at k8s.AbstractKubernetes.k8s.ICustomObjectsOperations.CreateClusterCustomObjectWithHttpMessagesAsync(Object body, String group, String version, String plural, String dryRun, String fieldManager, Nullable`1 pretty, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.KubernetesService.<>c__DisplayClass10_0`1.<<CreateAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext() in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/KubernetesService.cs:line 51
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.KubernetesService.ExecuteWithRetry[TResult](DcpApiOperationType operationType, String resourceType, Func`2 operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/KubernetesService.cs:line 198
         at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.KubernetesService.ExecuteWithRetry[TResult](DcpApiOperationType operationType, String resourceType, Func`2 operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/KubernetesService.cs:line 205
         at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.ApplicationExecutor.CreateResourcesAsync[RT](CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/ApplicationExecutor.cs:line 683
         at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.ApplicationExecutor.CreateServicesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/ApplicationExecutor.cs:line 124
         at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.ApplicationExecutor.RunApplicationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/ApplicationExecutor.cs:line 81
         at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.DcpHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/DcpHostService.cs:line 83
         at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.<StartAsync>b__15_1(IHostedService service, CancellationToken token)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.ForeachService[T](IEnumerable`1 services, CancellationToken token, Boolean concurrent, Boolean abortOnFirstException, List`1 exceptions, Func`3 operation)
Could not stop project 'apiservice': System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpIOException: The response ended prematurely. (ResponseEnded)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.EstablishProxyTunnelAsync(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp2ConnectionAsync(QueueItem queueItem)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   at k8s.Kubernetes.SendRequestRaw(String requestContent, HttpRequestMessage httpRequest, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at k8s.AbstractKubernetes.ICustomObjectsOperations_DeleteClusterCustomObjectWithHttpMessagesAsync[T](String group, String version, String plural, String name, V1DeleteOptions body, Nullable`1 gracePeriodSeconds, Nullable`1 orphanDependents, String propagationPolicy, String dryRun, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at k8s.AbstractKubernetes.k8s.ICustomObjectsOperations.DeleteClusterCustomObjectWithHttpMessagesAsync(String group, String version, String plural, String name, V1DeleteOptions body, Nullable`1 gracePeriodSeconds, Nullable`1 orphanDependents, String propagationPolicy, String dryRun, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.KubernetesService.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`1.<<DeleteAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext() in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/KubernetesService.cs:line 109
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.KubernetesService.ExecuteWithRetry[TResult](DcpApiOperationType operationType, String resourceType, Func`2 operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/KubernetesService.cs:line 198
   at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.KubernetesService.ExecuteWithRetry[TResult](DcpApiOperationType operationType, String resourceType, Func`2 operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/KubernetesService.cs:line 205
   at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.ApplicationExecutor.DeleteResourcesAsync[RT](String resourceName, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/ApplicationExecutor.cs:line 699
Could not stop project 'webfrontend': System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpIOException: The response ended prematurely. (ResponseEnded)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.EstablishProxyTunnelAsync(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp2ConnectionAsync(QueueItem queueItem)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   at k8s.Kubernetes.SendRequestRaw(String requestContent, HttpRequestMessage httpRequest, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at k8s.AbstractKubernetes.ICustomObjectsOperations_DeleteClusterCustomObjectWithHttpMessagesAsync[T](String group, String version, String plural, String name, V1DeleteOptions body, Nullable`1 gracePeriodSeconds, Nullable`1 orphanDependents, String propagationPolicy, String dryRun, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at k8s.AbstractKubernetes.k8s.ICustomObjectsOperations.DeleteClusterCustomObjectWithHttpMessagesAsync(String group, String version, String plural, String name, V1DeleteOptions body, Nullable`1 gracePeriodSeconds, Nullable`1 orphanDependents, String propagationPolicy, String dryRun, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.KubernetesService.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`1.<<DeleteAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext() in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/KubernetesService.cs:line 109
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.KubernetesService.ExecuteWithRetry[TResult](DcpApiOperationType operationType, String resourceType, Func`2 operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/KubernetesService.cs:line 198
   at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.KubernetesService.ExecuteWithRetry[TResult](DcpApiOperationType operationType, String resourceType, Func`2 operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/KubernetesService.cs:line 205
   at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.ApplicationExecutor.DeleteResourcesAsync[RT](String resourceName, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/ApplicationExecutor.cs:line 699
Could not stop container 'cache': System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpIOException: The response ended prematurely. (ResponseEnded)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.EstablishProxyTunnelAsync(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp2ConnectionAsync(QueueItem queueItem)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   at k8s.Kubernetes.SendRequestRaw(String requestContent, HttpRequestMessage httpRequest, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at k8s.AbstractKubernetes.ICustomObjectsOperations_DeleteClusterCustomObjectWithHttpMessagesAsync[T](String group, String version, String plural, String name, V1DeleteOptions body, Nullable`1 gracePeriodSeconds, Nullable`1 orphanDependents, String propagationPolicy, String dryRun, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at k8s.AbstractKubernetes.k8s.ICustomObjectsOperations.DeleteClusterCustomObjectWithHttpMessagesAsync(String group, String version, String plural, String name, V1DeleteOptions body, Nullable`1 gracePeriodSeconds, Nullable`1 orphanDependents, String propagationPolicy, String dryRun, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.KubernetesService.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`1.<<DeleteAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext() in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/KubernetesService.cs:line 109
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.KubernetesService.ExecuteWithRetry[TResult](DcpApiOperationType operationType, String resourceType, Func`2 operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/KubernetesService.cs:line 198
   at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.KubernetesService.ExecuteWithRetry[TResult](DcpApiOperationType operationType, String resourceType, Func`2 operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/KubernetesService.cs:line 205
   at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.ApplicationExecutor.DeleteResourcesAsync[RT](String resourceName, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/ApplicationExecutor.cs:line 699
Could not stop service 'cache': System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpIOException: The response ended prematurely. (ResponseEnded)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.EstablishProxyTunnelAsync(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp2ConnectionAsync(QueueItem queueItem)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   at k8s.Kubernetes.SendRequestRaw(String requestContent, HttpRequestMessage httpRequest, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at k8s.AbstractKubernetes.ICustomObjectsOperations_DeleteClusterCustomObjectWithHttpMessagesAsync[T](String group, String version, String plural, String name, V1DeleteOptions body, Nullable`1 gracePeriodSeconds, Nullable`1 orphanDependents, String propagationPolicy, String dryRun, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at k8s.AbstractKubernetes.k8s.ICustomObjectsOperations.DeleteClusterCustomObjectWithHttpMessagesAsync(String group, String version, String plural, String name, V1DeleteOptions body, Nullable`1 gracePeriodSeconds, Nullable`1 orphanDependents, String propagationPolicy, String dryRun, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.KubernetesService.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`1.<<DeleteAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext() in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/KubernetesService.cs:line 109
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.KubernetesService.ExecuteWithRetry[TResult](DcpApiOperationType operationType, String resourceType, Func`2 operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.KubernetesService.ExecuteWithRetry[TResult](DcpApiOperationType operationType, String resourceType, Func`2 operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/KubernetesService.cs:line 205
   at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.ApplicationExecutor.DeleteResourcesAsync[RT](String resourceName, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/ApplicationExecutor.cs:line 699
```

Answer (score 0):

AppHost won't work within a container as it needs to be able to talk to Docker/Podman to create shared resources.

For example, if you add Redis as an Aspire component the is shared between an API and a Web frontend, how would the AppHost create the component in a container if it is already running inside the container?

I reviewed your stack trace and noticed a few hints that Aspire is trying to create a container/k8s cluster.

> at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.KubernetesService.ExecuteWithRetry[TResult](DcpApiOperationType operationType, String resourceType, Func`2 operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/KubernetesService.cs:line 198 at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.KubernetesService.ExecuteWithRetry[TResult](DcpApiOperationType operationType, String resourceType, Func`2 operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /*/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/KubernetesService.cs:line 205
> at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.ApplicationExecutor.CreateResourcesAsync[RT](CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /*/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/ApplicationExecutor.cs:line 683
> at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.ApplicationExecutor.CreateServicesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /*/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/ApplicationExecutor.cs:line 124
> at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.ApplicationExecutor.RunApplicationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /*/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/ApplicationExecutor.cs:line 81
> at Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.DcpHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/Aspire.Hosting/Dcp/DcpHostService.cs:line 83
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.b__15_1(IHostedService service, CancellationToken token)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.ForeachService[T](IEnumerable`1 services, CancellationToken token, Boolean concurrent, Boolean abortOnFirstException, List`1 exceptions, Func`3 operation)

I'm not sure if this would ever be possible as Aspire will always require an orchestrator outside of the container host to create those containers. And asAppHost is already that orchestrator, creating another one for AppHost to talk to would be mean creating a needless middleman.